# Dynamic SQL - Picking the values from the temp table

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamics-crm-2011, audit-trail

I have a temp table that has the following information.

> TableName  ColumnName PrimaryKeyColumnName  Primarykey(A GUID)

(4 columns)

I need to include one more new column Value that should grab data based on the condition below

"for each row in the temp table"

```
select ColumnName from  TableName  where PrimaryKeyColumnName  = Primarykey
```

To be even more precise , the query must retrieve the values from the table directly.

I am sure this can be achieved using cursor. But it might impact my query performance. 
Could this be achieved using sp_sqlexecute? I tried converting the query as a `varchar`.

Like this

```
set @sql = 'select '+ #final.[primary field] +'from ' + #final.tablename +
                'where '+ #final.PrimaryKeyColumnName  + '='+ #final.Primarykey  

exec sp_sqlexecute  @sql
```

Answer (score 1):

Possible this be helpful for you -

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#temp') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #temp
GO

CREATE TABLE #temp
(
    [primary field] SYSNAME,
    tablename SYSNAME,
    PrimaryKeyColumnName SYSNAME,
    Primarykey SYSNAME
)

INSERT INTO #temp ([primary field], tablename, PrimaryKeyColumnName, Primarykey) 
VALUES 
    ('[column1]','[table1]','[column3]', '[column12]'), 
    ('[column2]','[table2]','[column4]', '[column24]')


DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @SQL = (
    SELECT CHAR(13) + 'SELECT '+ [primary field] + ' FROM ' + tablename +
        ' WHERE '+ PrimaryKeyColumnName  + ' = '+ Primarykey 
    FROM #temp
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')

PRINT @SQL
--EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL
```

Output -

```
SELECT [column1] FROM [table1] WHERE [column3] = [column12]
SELECT [column2] FROM [table2] WHERE [column4] = [column24]
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch. This is what I was expecting. I was afraid my question would be clear enough to be understood. You saved the day.

Comment: And how do I update the value to main table.For instance update #final set @somecolumnname= exec sys.sp_executesql @SQL

Comment: Can you provide a small example?

Comment: Hi please find the example I have posted above

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that I understood what you are trying to do but try this:

```
declare @sql varchar(8000);
set @sql = null;
select @sql = 
coalesce(@sql+' union all select '+ColumnName+' from '+ tablename,  
'select '+ColumnName+' from '+ tablename) 
from final where ColumnName = PrimaryKeyColumnName;
exec sp_sqlexecute @sql;
```

Notice that the @sql is limited -in my sample 8000- if the temp table you have is too big you gonna have to make a separate executes,needs some changes in the code.
Always you have to set an initial value for @SQL as null.
I think no need for cursor, this will be solved using some SQL tricks. 
Hope this will help...

Answer (score 0):

Create Table #tempValueFetch

(

```
TableName sysname,
PrimaryKeyColumnName sysname,
AttributeColumnName sysname,
Primaryfield sysname,
PrimaryKey sysname,
Label nvarchar(max),
Value nvarchar(max)
```

)

this temp table has been populated with 5 columns namely TableName,PrimaryKeyColumnName,AttributeColumnName ,Primaryfield ,PrimaryKey

The columns label and value has to updated dynamically.Note that primary key is a uniqueidentifier